# convert 2D data.frame into 3D Array

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, mnist

I´m failing to convert a 2D dataframe into an 3D Array.

How can I convert a 42000x784 dataframe into an 42000x28x28 3D array in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `dim` perhaps?

Comment: like train_a <- array(train_x,dim=c(nrow(train),28,28)) ? because R-Studio shows me that the resulting array is 5TB in size? bug?

Comment: Like `M <- matrix(1:36, 4, 9); "dim<-"(M, c(4, 3, 3))`....

Comment: It's better if you can add What you have tried so far.

Comment: I suspect no bug but rather failure to build the starting matrix properly. You should post the output from `str(train)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a numeric matrix then it should only take `42000*784 *10 == 329280000` bytes. If it's a character vector it could be larger depending on the number of unique items in the underlying values. I did attempt finding a duplicate using searches on "[r] matrix re-dimension" without success, although I did find answers that cautioned one about re-dimensioning with `dim<-`, so read this caveat: When you want to re-dimension a matrix AND are keeping the first dimension untouched, then it is a very simple procedure. (If that's not the task, then you may need other array tools such as `abind::abind` or `aperm`.) The code below is basically partitioning the columns so that adjacent columns in the matrix stay mostly "adjacent" within slices of the array (except obviously at the partitioning "breaks"). Try:

```
train_a  <- train # make copy
dim(train_a) < c(42000,28,28)  # re-dimension
```

Try it with a smaller matrix:

```
 mymat <- matrix(1:36, 4,9)
 mymat_a <- mymat
 dim(mymat_a) <- c(4, 3,3)

> mymat_a
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   17   21
[2,]   14   18   22
[3,]   15   19   23
[4,]   16   20   24

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   25   29   33
[2,]   26   30   34
[3,]   27   31   35
[4,]   28   32   36
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by IRTFM works for matrices, but not for dataframes.
If it was a dataframe, you'd have to unlist it first.

```
mymat <- matrix(1:36, 4,9)
mydf <- as.data.frame(mymat)

mydf_a <- unlist(mydf)
dim( mydf_a ) <- c(4, 3,3)

> mydf
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
1  1  5  9 13 17 21 25 29 33
2  2  6 10 14 18 22 26 30 34
3  3  7 11 15 19 23 27 31 35
4  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36

> mydf_a
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   17   21
[2,]   14   18   22
[3,]   15   19   23
[4,]   16   20   24

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   25   29   33
[2,]   26   30   34
[3,]   27   31   35
[4,]   28   32   36
```